# make ion nav bar responsive for different orientation

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to set my ion nav bar responsive for every screen size or orientation.from my code its height changes as i view it with landscape orientation.

```
  <ion-nav-bar class=" blue" >
          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <!-- <button class="button  button-icon  ion-navicon blue" menu-
            toggle="left"></button>-->
            <button class="button button-clear" menu-toggle="left"><img 
            src="img\menu.png"  width="22" style="vertical-align: middle">
           </button>
           <img src="img\logo.png" width="33vw"   style="vertical-align: 
           middle" >
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar></div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue{
    background:#082865;
    height:10vh;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using width in 'vw' provide it in percentages like 100% or whatever% u like.
Same is the case with your nav-bar provide its width in %age.

Hope it helps!